# getContext() cannot be resolved in SQLite dB

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-contacts

I'm trying to create an SQL database to store local contact information (mainly just phone# (to be verify at a later time) and display name, along with a user-specified boolean. I created a new contactdb class, but I ran into some bumps when trying to use getcontext(). Secondary values for put are also not able to be resolved. Does anyone have any hints in how to go about solving this? Do I need to create a new class file for Dbhelper? Or is that bit meant to be instantialized within the mainactivity class, wherein I wish to read / write information to the DB?

```
package treehouse.greenlight;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.view.View;

public final class contactdb {
// To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
// give it an empty constructor.
public contactdb() {
}

/* Inner class that defines the table contents */
public static abstract class dbEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
    public static final Boolean COLUMN_NAME_STATUS = false;
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PHONE = "0000000000";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "N/A";
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + dbEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    dbEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    dbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    dbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    dbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PHONE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +// Any other options for the CREATE command
                    " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbEntry.TABLE_NAME;


    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);


            // Gets the data repository in write mode
            db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(dbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, id);
            values.put(dbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS, status);
            values.put(dbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PHONE, content);

            // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
            long newRowId;
            newRowId = db.insert(
                    dbEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    dbEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE,
                    values);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
            // to simply to discard the data and start over
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database is not extended from `Activity`, so this method is unreachable.
You should create constructor which receives `Context` as parameter from `Activity`. And your code should look like this:

```
private Context ctx;

public contactdb(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

And in your `Activity` you should create instance like this:

```
contactdb db = new contactdb(this);
```

And please, name your classes from uppercase letter. Research a little about code convention in java.

Comment: There is no getContext in an Activity either, an Activity is a Context.  It exists in Views and a few other classes.

Comment: Activity is extended from the Context, it calls down casting, so `this` means in `Activity` context itself. Anyways, question was about solving problem how to reach context, not about theory, but this is my typo, I agree. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys -- I think this makes sense. So I should create the constructor in my ContactDb class (and also set ContactDb extends Home_screen). From there, I can call it in the Home_screen activity itself by instantiating it with the new db this reference?

Comment: @Shyam, `Home_screen` is your `Activity`? is yes, no you shouldn't do that. Just add `Context` as parameter to your constructor and in `Activity` when you create instance of database and pass `this`. Also inner class `DBHelper` make `private`, it makes more sense.

Comment: So I shouldn't extend Home_screen in the ContactDb class? Also if ctx is private, doesn't that mean my Activity cannot resolve it?

Comment: `public final class ContactDb {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public ContactDb() {


    }
    private static Context ctx;

    public ContactDb(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }` I've created the constructor which receives Context as a parameter. Later on however when I try to reference ctx `DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(ctx());` I'm told it is expecting a method call -- I tried placing this inside the parenthesis but had no luck. Is all of this meant to be passed in Home_screen?

Comment: @Shyam, you shouldn't ever make context static. Please follow this code in answer. there is exactly what you need.

Comment: Sorry -- I did that because i was told that non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context. It was an error in the brackets and I have fixed it. I think this solution should work. All the calls to edit the database should be done from the main activity though, correct? Home_screen (info such as put, drop, etc)

Comment: @Shyam, yes, in any of your activities you create instance of database and after you will be able to call methods which you create in your database class, such as insertMyLines, queryAllRecords and any other you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Yurets. This makes sense and I think I have sorted most of the bugs out.

Comment: There is one issue with this approach. If you try to make this db class singleton, the static instance will show a warning that it can not have Context as member variable as it is a memory leak.!

Comment: @RahulRaveendran, if you want to use singleton you can find different approach. The answer did not mean to be the only solution, scalable, generic and fit all the cases.

Comment: @Yurets: Sorry I did not mean it in that way. I was just trying to point out one issue I faced while using this approach. That's all. :)

Comment: @RahulRaveendran, no problem at all. Just the question was asked as a very basic, so I didn't even try to cover best practices. Just general approach to his problem :)

Answer (score 0):

getContext doesn't exist for SQLiteOpenHelper.  A Context is passed into the constructor.  Wait until then to create your variables that need it.

Also, your code as written would crash-  it would create an infinite loop of instantiating new DBHelper objects.  Putting Foo name = new Foo()  inside of a Foo object will always crash.

Comment: Hi Gabe, thank you very much for the heads up! I've moved the DBhelper outside of the object. When exactly would I create this constructor? In the actual database class file or in the activity when I want to access the db, put, drop, etc?